# Angular2 multi-list picker iOS style

Tags: css, angular, typescript, uicomponents

Does anyone know of a UI component similar to [this one](https://github.com/mmnaseri/proton.multi-list-picker) for Angular 2?

I am looking for a UI Component that looks like the iOS UIPickerView which displays a beveled look with the selected item in the middle for a project I am working on.